# REST equivalent for getting envelope history RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken soap call

Tags: docusignapi

We are currently using the RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken SOAP service to retrieve the docusign envelope history and display in our application.Looking for a REST API equivalent for this function.Is there a equivalent REST call?

Answer (score 2):

There is and I recently wrote a blog post all about it - https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-parsing-envelopes-audit-events

tl;dr it's **Envelopes
: listAuditEvents** - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/listauditevents

Comment: Thanks,isnt there a single api that would display the envelope history ,return as a url (RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken SOAP used to do that)instead of us having to parse through the audit events?

Comment: There isn't because the idea was to give you the information as data, not as a ready made display. What you do with the data is up to you.